# CRM 2013 - Is there a onChange function for a Grid

Tags: javascript, plugins, dynamics-crm-2011

I have a grid which users can add products too

I have a plugin that executed when there is a update to the record, however when a product is added the plugin/CRM doesn't recognise that as a update to the record therefore the plugin doesn't execute.

Is there a OnChange function I can access through JavaScript for the Grid so that I can change the value of a hidden field so that then a change has been made to the record, therefore a update being recognised and the plugin being executed?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is a no SDK function to add a JavaScript event when an item is added to a grid is CRM 2011/2013.

The correct way to handle this requirement is in a plug-in.

Records appear in a grid when they are related to the parent record - either a one-to-many relationship or as a many-to-many relationship.

If it is a one-to-many relationship you can trigger on the `Create` and `Update` of the many side (since it will contain a reference to the one side.) If it is a many-to-many you'll need to trigger on `Association` as [shown here in a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12173818/how-do-i-add-a-crm-plugin-step-on-a-many-to-many-intersect-table).

Answer (score 1):

One way to handle this situation would be add a on-create plugin for the Products - which can trigger the On Change plugin for the record in the similar fashion as you are trying to.
Essentially, oncreate plugin will update the record which will fire the on update plugin of the record. This would be the case if the relationship is 1:N

If its a N:N relationship, then the plugin should be registered on Associate / Diassociate, not on create / update.

In fact, the question is not clear, hence the two options above.

Comment: No, there is a no SDK function to add a JavaScript event when an item is added to a grid is CRM 2011/2013. What you can do is use a plugin. I agree with Nalashaa that question needs some clarification.